# Using Visual Studio "Browse with" option with arguments opens a tab for each character

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So I have created a new entry in the "Browse with" with --incognito arguments

[image]

once I hit F5/start debugging, Visual studio opens Chrome but it is interpreting the arguments as a webpage or something like that. It opens a tab for every character of the argument line:

[image: Multiple tabs]

If I double click the new entry or hit "Browse" button in the "Browse With" dialog, it opens correctly as incognito.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 professional by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug intoduced in recent versions of Visual Studio. It was raised on the Visual Studio Developer Community in May and Microsoft responded with a work around as follows:

> "If you are impacted by this bug please enable the legacy Chrome debugger from under 'Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable legacy Chrome JavaScript debugger for ASP.NET' to be unblocked."

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/248237/cannot-browsedebug-chrome-incognito-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

This silly bug has been driving me nuts for a couple of days now!

Actually to me the easiest was to use Vivaldi instead of Chrome which works as intended with flags so this made me to think that this maybe isn't a Visual Studio bug but in Chrome?

Anyway, there's [plenty of Chromium-based browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)#Other_browsers_based_on_Chromium) out there you can try out if you do not like Vivaldi ;)