# Launch browser in chrome as application via asp.net web application properties page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

On the debug page of an asp.net project there is the option to 'Launch Browser'

I would like this to launch the browser with no nav bar or tab options.

This is possible with chrome - you can create a shortcut to chrome and pass

```
"chrome.exe" --app="url"
```

I cannot seem to get the same effect when launching a browser from the properties page. I have tried various different application arguments, environment variables, etc to no avail.

Is it possible to launch the browser via this properties page without a nav bar and tab interface? (ie launch it as an application)

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom 'Browse With' targets

[image: browse with]

[image: add]

[image: enter params]

[image: chrome app mode]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however I cant seem to get it to work. So the program field points to google chrome - whats the argument i pass to run it in application mode (no nav bar/tabs). If I place --app in the program it fails to create the browser - if i place it in the arguments section it will open multiple tabs one with each letter of --app

Comment: I've added another image but it looks like you may hvae come up against a bug in VS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879735/using-visual-studio-browse-with-option-with-arguments-opens-a-tab-for-each-cha

Comment: Your extra image is how I would have expected it to work; shame about the bug. I have managed to find a work around - if you create a .bat file that runs chrome you can pass arguments to that. Then when browsing for a browser - select the .bat file (need to change the filter from .exe to all files)